# Ms access having problems with relationships

Tags: ms-access-2007, relationships

I'm a learner and trying to create 1 to many relationship between two tables: 
`Emp(eid, ename, designation)` where `eid` is primary key and table `pay(desigId, designation, salary)` where `desigId` is primary key. On enforcing referential integrity and creating relationship, I'm getting message ms access can't create this relationship and enforce referential integrity. Data in table Emp violates integrity rules. For example, there may be records relating to employee in the related table, but no record for employee in the primary table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have data that violates the relationship you want to build. to find the invalid data run this sql

```
SELECT pay.eid
FROM pay LEFT JOIN Emp ON pay.eid = Emp.eid
WHERE Emp.eid Is Null
```

Comment: it is so confusing... there is no pay.id in my table.

Comment: in my table emp, i have eid as e1, e2, e3,....e8. ename as A,B,...H and designation as electrical engineer for e1 and e3, mechanical engineer for e2 and e4, system analyst for e5 and e6, programmer for e7 and e8. and my pay table has desigId as d1, d2, d3, d4; designation as electrical engineer, mechanical engineer, system analyst, programmer.